# Fotorama: how should I initialize Fotorama that is created dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, fotorama

I wish to use Fotorama in my project. But my project uses AngularJS to load the partial view which contains

```
<div class="fotorama">
<img src="1.jpg"><img src="2.jpg"><img src="3.jpg">
</div>
```

But that cannot initialize fotorama since the html is loaded via AJAX.

How should I load Fotorama under this situation?

The problem is I think similar to handling event on element created dynamically. For instance,

```
<div class="myImg">Some Img</div>
```

And you write,

```
$('.myImg').on('click', function() {
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

The alert won't fire if the div is created dynamically. But the following would work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myImg', function() {
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

I think the same case is true for fotorama. So how should I do similar thing for the case of Fotorama?

Thank you very much.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You may check official documentation: http://fotorama.io/customize/api/
Or use one of angular wrappers: https://github.com/tamtakoe/ap.fotorama
Probably, you have to parse images from HTML chunk, or redesign it all (sending HTML by AJAX isn't good approach) to send JSON. Something like this:

```
$('.fotorama').fotorama({
    data: [
      {img: '1.jpg', thumb: '1-thumb.jpg'},
      {img: '2.jpg', thumb: '2-thumb.jpg'}
    ]
});
```

Or like this (will modify existing fotorama instance):

```
fotorama.load([
  {img: '1.jpg', thumb: '1-thumb.jpg'},
  {img: '2.jpg', thumb: '2-thumb.jpg'}
]);
```

**PS**
If you going to create DOM element dynamically, you should add event listeners after it been added to document. for example

```
$.get({/* url, etc */})
  .success(plainHtml) {
    $('el').append(plainHtml)
    $('selector').on('click', onClickCallback)
  })
```

Also, you can manually initialize fotorama on the DOM element: $('.fotorama').fotorama(). In onSuccess callback, of course. Actually, you shouldn't use jQuery in AngularJs projects.

Comment: Really thank you for your answer. I have edited my question. My problem seems to be that the fotorama does not activate, rather than the problem of loading picture. I shouldn't use Fotorama with AngularJS partial view, should I?